# Deregister oldest task definition in ecs with aws cli

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have to remove old task definitions from aws cli?
Does any one have idea or any useful links that i can follow.

From console we can do manually but is there any automation we can set here?

Answer (score 0):

e.g. `aws ecs deregister-task-definition --task-definition curler:1` ?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/deregister-task-definition.html

Comment: yes. we can but can we get list of old task definition via aws cli or any other way we can remove task definition which are older than few days via script.

Comment: e.g. `aws ecs list-task-definitions` ? 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/list-task-definitions.html

Answer (score 0):

I did this quick and dirty script to deregister all old task definitions (and always keep the last active one).

It requires awscli v2 and jq:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


CURRENT_TASK_DEFINITION=
CURRENT_FAMILY_LIST=()
for row in $(aws ecs list-task-definitions --status ACTIVE | jq -r '.taskDefinitionArns[] | @base64'); do
  _jq() {
   echo ${row} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}
  }
  _decode() {
    echo ${row} | base64 --decode
  }

  ARN=$(_decode)
  TASK_DEFINITION_AND_FAMILY=$(echo $ARN | cut -d "/" -f2 )
  TASK_DEFINITION=$(echo $TASK_DEFINITION_AND_FAMILY | cut -d ":" -f1 )
  FAMILY=$(echo $TASK_DEFINITION_AND_FAMILY | cut -d ":" -f2 )

  if [ "$CURRENT_TASK_DEFINITION" == "" ]; then
    CURRENT_TASK_DEFINITION=$TASK_DEFINITION
  fi
  if [ "$CURRENT_TASK_DEFINITION" == "$TASK_DEFINITION" ]; then
    CURRENT_FAMILY_LIST+=( $FAMILY )
  else
    echo "Families for $CURRENT_TASK_DEFINITION: ${CURRENT_FAMILY_LIST[*]}"

    for FAMILY_TO_DESTROY in "${CURRENT_FAMILY_LIST[@]::${#CURRENT_FAMILY_LIST[@]}-1}"
    do
       echo "Deregistering family $CURRENT_TASK_DEFINITION:$FAMILY_TO_DESTROY"

       aws ecs deregister-task-definition --task-definition $CURRENT_TASK_DEFINITION:$FAMILY_TO_DESTROY --no-cli-pager

       sleep 1
    done

    CURRENT_TASK_DEFINITION=$TASK_DEFINITION
    CURRENT_FAMILY_LIST=( $FAMILY )
  fi
done
```